# How to find the bookmark i'm tracking in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

When I use `hg bookmarks` it does not display the bookmark i'm tracking when my bookmark is master (created with `arc feature master`). If I have a custom bookmark it does highlight the bookmark being tracked. Is there a way to find which remote bookmark is currently being tracked?

Comment: This is probably a phabricator question. Are you sure `arc` is activating the bookmark? If it's not highlighted in "hg bookmark" that indicates the answer is no.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "tracking a bookmark". `hg id`or `hg log` will show you the currently checked-out bookmark.

Comment: @ngoldbaum You're right the bookmark (master) does not get highlighted.